# Shiny element position on a page: Display one box per row in the application

Tags: r, shiny

[image]I have designed UI which has 'infoBox' within 'box'. 
I want each box at a time and the next box should be shown in next line.
But I am getting two boxes in a row. How to avoid such error?

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "red",
dashboardHeader(title = "sample"),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
menuItem("a"))),
dashboardBody( 
tabPanel(h5("Labtest"),
box(h3("Hypertension"),
infoBox("Normal", "..." ,"Screened", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
infoBox("Pre-Hypertension", "..." ,"Screened", icon = icon('male'), width = 
4),
infoBox("Hypertension" , "..." ,"Screened", icon = icon('female'), width = 
4)), 
box(h3("RBS"),
infoBox("Normal", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
infoBox("Pre-Diabetic", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('male'), width = 4),
infoBox("Diabetic", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('female'), width = 4)), 
box(h3("HB"),
infoBox("Normal", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
infoBox("Pre-Diabetic", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('male'), width = 
4)), 
box(h3("Malaria"),
infoBox("Total Beneficiaries", "...", "referred to BBCI", icon = 
icon('users'), width = 4),
infoBox("suspected", "...", "referred to BBCI", icon = icon("male"), width = 
4)))
)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: did you try and wrap each `box` in a `fluidRow()`? This will put each `box` on a new row.

Comment: Yes I tried with fluidRow(). The box is coming as row but the width remains same. It is not displaying at full row width. It is showing in half row width only.

Comment: Then you need to adapt the box width. I added it in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap each `box` in a `fluidRow`. Also set the `width` of the `box` to `100%` else they will not cover the entire width of your application.

By wrapping your widgets in a `fluidRow` you can make sure in which line they are located. By wrapping them in a `column` you can set the horizontal space of a widget.

**Your application:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                            dashboardHeader(title = "sample"),
                            dashboardSidebar(
                              sidebarMenu(
                                menuItem("a"))),
                            dashboardBody( 
                              tabPanel(h5("Labtest"),
                                       fluidRow(style='margin: 0px;',
                                         box(width='100%',
                                           h3("Hypertension"),
                                             infoBox("Normal", "..." ,"Screened", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
                                             infoBox("Pre-Hypertension", "..." ,"Screened", icon = icon('male'), width = 
                                                       4),
                                             infoBox("Hypertension" , "..." ,"Screened", icon = icon('female'), width = 
                                                       4))), 
                                       fluidRow(style='margin: 0px;',
                                         box(width='100%',
                                             h3("RBS"),
                                             infoBox("Normal", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
                                             infoBox("Pre-Diabetic", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('male'), width = 4),
                                             infoBox("Diabetic", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('female'), width = 4))), 
                                       fluidRow(style='margin: 0px;',
                                         box(width='100%',
                                             h3("HB"),
                                             infoBox("Normal", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
                                             infoBox("Pre-Diabetic", "...", "Suspected", icon = icon('male'), width = 
                                                     4))), 
                                       fluidRow(style='margin: 0px;',
                                         box(width='100%',
                                           h3("Malaria"),
                                           infoBox("Total Beneficiaries", "...", "referred to BBCI", icon = 
                                                     icon('users'), width = 4),
                                           infoBox("suspected", "...", "referred to BBCI", icon = icon("male"), width = 
                                                     4))))
                            )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

})
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the info boxes you want in a column function. 
Something like,

```
column(width = 4,
    Box(width = NULL,
      infoBox(1),
      infoBox(2),

  )
)
column(width = 4,
     Box(width = NULL,
       infoBox(3)
  ))
```