# Placing one box per row in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

First time poster here.

**1. Background**

I want to create a dynamic UI of boxes and graphs placed inside those boxes in `shinydashboard`. I found this blogpost that perfectly suits my needs: [Create a dynamic number of UI elements in Shiny with purrr](https://tbradley1013.github.io/2018/08/10/create-a-dynamic-number-of-ui-elements-in-shiny-with-purrr/)

**2. Problem**

There is just one design element that I'd like to change. Currently, the dashboard contains two boxes per `fluidRow` because each box has `width=6`. I could change the width to 12 to solve my problem, but I wanted to see if I could create one box of `width=6` per row. I've tried to include a `br()` but that doesn't do much.

Here's what my minimal example looks like:

[Minimal App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v82Ae.png)

**3. Code**

Here's my code

```
# Load packages---------
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinymanager)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)


# Create function that plots graphs
plot_mtcars <- function(df) {
  
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = "Weight",
         y = "Miles per gallon")
  
  
}




# Start of shinydashboard---------
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Minimal App",
  titleWidth = 240
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  # Width of the sidebar (in pixels)
  width = 240,
  sidebarMenu(
    
    h1("Welcome!"),
    menuItem(text = "WEEKLY RESULTS", tabName = "weekly_results")
  )
  

)

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "weekly_results", 
            
            
            fluidRow(
              
              uiOutput(outputId = "graphs_ui")            
            )
            
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", header = header,
                    sidebar = sidebar,
                    body = body)




server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  mtcars_reactive <- reactive({
    
    mtcars %>% 
      head(8) %>% 
      mutate(car_names = rownames(head(mtcars, 8)))
    
  })
    
  
  
  # Create reactive graphs
  graphs <- reactive({
    
    mtcars_reactive() %>% 
      group_by(car_names) %>% 
      nest() %>% 
      mutate(
        graphs = map(data, plot_mtcars)) %>% 
      pull(graphs)
    
  })
  
  
  output$graphs_ui <- renderUI({
   
    
    iwalk(graphs(), ~{
      output_name <- paste0("plot_", .y)
      output[[output_name]] <- renderPlot(.x)
    })
    
    
    plots_list <- imap(graphs(), ~{
      
      tagList(
        
        
        tags$div(class = "another-box", id = paste0("danger", .y, "_id"),
                 box(width = 6,
                     title = "Mtcars Data", 
                     status = "danger", solidHeader = TRUE,
                     plotOutput(outputId = paste0("plot_", .y)), 
                     ""
                 ),
                 tags$style(HTML(
                   paste0( 
                     "
                        #danger", .y, "_id .box.box-solid.box-danger>.box-header {
                        color:#fff;
                        background:", "#FF0000","
                        }

                        #danger", .y, "_id .box.box-solid.box-danger {
                        border-bottom-color:", "#FF0000", ";
                        border-left-color:", "#FF0000", ";
                        border-right-color:", "#FF0000",";
                        border-top-color:", "#FF0000", ";
                        }

                        "
                   )
                 )) 
        ),
        
        br()
        
        
      )
      
    })
    
    tagList(plots_list)
    
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shiny element position on a page: Display one box per row in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481492/shiny-element-position-on-a-page-display-one-box-per-row-in-the-application)

Answer (score 0):

Default width of `box()` is 6.  You can specify the width you want as shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width=12,plotOutput("plot2"))),
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot3"))
      #,box(DTOutput("table"))
      ),
    fluidRow(box(width=4,plotOutput("plot1")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDT(head(iris))
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(pressure))
    output$plot3 <- renderPlot(plot(airquality))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. As I mentioned, I could change the width to 12 to solve my problem, but I wanted to see if I could create one box of width=6 per row.

Comment: Please try the updated code again.  First row is width 12, then 6 and the last one is width 4.

Comment: I've just tried your code. As I mentioned, I don't want to be manually changing widths every row. I want a `width=6` for every box.

Comment: default width is 6.  This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your minimal example code, you can change `class = "another-box"` to `class = "row"` to wrap each box in a row div. If you want to keep `another-box` class , you can also just add `row` as a class, i.e. `class = "another-box row"`. Alternatively, you can use the Shiny function `fluidRow()` to wrap something in a row div.

For more info, see [Boostrap Grid Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/)